# Какие методы и операторы необходимо использовать для того, чтоб бот при перепосте заменял одно слово на другое?

Tags: telegram-bot

Я сам не очень хорошо понимаю Python, только начинаю его изучать. Появилась необходимость сделать бота, который пересылает сообщения из одного канала в другой, при этом в сообщениях нужно заменять два слова на их иностранный аналог. Слова одинаковые, потому именно в функции перевода, думаю, нет нужды, ибо это явно будет сложнее. Сам бот, который пересылает сообщения, у меня есть. Какие варианты есть для реализации функции замены двух определенных слов на два другие, и где они в принципе должны быть в коде реализованы?

```
@app.on_message()
def resend(client, message):
    try:
        if message.from_user.is_bot: return
        if resend_from in (message.from_user.username, message.from_user.id):
            client.forward_messages(chat_id=resend_to, from_chat_id=message.chat.id, message_ids=message.message_id)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот, работает благодаря `lmsg.replace('hello', 'привет')`

```
import telebot 

bot = telebot.TeleBot("ТОКЕН")   

@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def default_test(message):
    lmsg = message.text.lower()
    if "hello" in lmsg:
        msg = lmsg.replace('hello', 'привет')
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, msg)  
          
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, lmsg) 
        
bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

*Если ответ помог, поставь слева от моего ответа галочку*

Comment: Буду пробовать, если всё заработает дам знать) Только подскажите, данные строчки кода необходимо вставлять после 6 строчки моего примера? и могу ли я использовать вместо токена api_id и hash_id? У меня они используются просто уже и сохранены в .env файле. Может с вами можно связаться вообще и скинуть весь код, дабы могли подсказать конкретнее, что и куда?)

Comment: Да, давай свяжемся, пиши в тг - @Zelebobins